# how to insert <a> tag in inside <input> tag

Tags: html, css

I want to create forgot password button or `<a>` tag in inside `<input>` tag. And I want to right align the `<a>` tag in `<input>` but I got stuck.

```html
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password" class="text-gray">Password</label>

              <input
                type="password"
                class="form-control form-field"
                placeholder="Password"
              /><a href="">Forgot</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: The [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element is void (self closing). That means its not mean't to contain any text or elements. Please update your question with more details on what your looking to achieve, its currently not clear.

Comment: Also inputs and buttons cannot contain links it's invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you can make it appear that way with some good CSS and HTML:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
input {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input placeholder="Forgot on an input! -->" />
  <div class="icon"><a href="#">Forgot</a></div><!-The blue block to the right-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    This is editable
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

To be able to do that the best way is a `contenteditable` div. As it is editable and a div you can use the html markup here.